# What technology do apps use for real time syncing of data?

Tags: ios

A lot of apps such as Uber, Lyft, and GroupMe seem like they have real-time data getting pushed down from the server. Obviously they could be faking it by refreshing every n seconds. Another thought was that they could be opening TCP sockets? Or potentially other technologies that I am unaware of.

If programming an iOS app what is the industry standard for syncing data between the client and the server in real time, without user interaction such as swiping up?

Comment: Why was my question downvoted? It seems perfectly valid to me...

Comment: (I'm not the downvoter) ... Likely because it's very broad and doesn't show a lot of research on your part.  Socket technology for example is very well understood and with a modicum of effort on your part to understand it, you would see why it is a good choice for real-time delivery of information.

Answer (score 2):

WebSockets or polling are the general solutions. Push Notifications can also be used to trigger a poll in some cases.

Comment: WebSockets, possibly, polling, no.  Polling is horrible for any system with a large user base.  It would simply not be viable for something as widely used as Uber.

Comment: I agree polling is not scalable, but that wasn't what the OP asked. Many apps do use polling successfully because their user base is small enough.

Comment: OP asked about industry standard practices related to real-time data delivery and references some massively-deployed apps.  Asynchronous notifications *are* the industry standard because they are both performant and low-overhead.  This is a use case where polling is simply not used by anyone who knows what they're doing (even in small-scale applications).

Comment: I hate to disagree, but I develop an app with about 10k DAU and we use polling successfully. We're in the process of migrating away from it, but it works to get an app to maturity and let the team focus on validating the concept rather than worrying about scaling in the begining

Comment: Nothing wrong with disagreement, but I don't see how you gain anything from polling.  Development time to build a polling solution is roughly the same as an asynchronous one, and as you've seen at 10K daily users you've realized you have to replace it.  That's painful (and undoubtedly expensive).  Now that you know this, if you had to do it again would you start off with a polling solution?  My most recent large project has millions of monthly users and often high ten's to 100K+ *simultaneous* users. There's no way a polling solution would be feasible and we knew that from the start.

Comment: One of the essays by Paul Graham that I like is [Do Things That Don't Scale](http://www.paulgraham.com/ds.html). In our case, we had a choice between getting to market with what we had or spend several months more to make a scalable solution. Now that we have revenue coming in, we can deal with the scaling issues. I agree it's not harder to build it "right" from the start, but it's hard to know what "right" looks like at the beginning. We built a web app initially and JSON services to support it. Those same JSON services were what we launched our initial app with.

Comment: +1 for not knowing what right looks like at the beginning (and for making a product that works).  I'm a big fan of *shipping*, however you get there.

Comment: Just to make sure I'm clear about this, I'll state this explicitly: if you think you need a syncing infrastructure, don't build a polling system. However, if that's all you've got, it can work short term. Thanks for the great discussion Par.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Neal's answer, check out the Rocket technique, which "leverages web standards like [Server-Sent Events](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-sent_events) and [JSON Patch](http://jsonpatch.com/)."

[AFRocketClient](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFRocketClient) uses AFNetworking to support this on iOS/Mac, as long as the server supports these technologies.